# ng-if="check(document)" function in Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I really need your help, this is more angular specified trouble. I have created ng-click test button

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="document in filtered = (documents | filter: searchFilter | filter: {category_id: categoryFilter.id}: false | orderBy: sortBy)"  type="item-text-wrap">
  <div class="document-functions">
    <form name="downloadForm" method="post" ng-submit="download(document)">
      <button class="buttons button-document-save" ng-if="check(document)">Save</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

with function

```
$scope.check = function(document) {
  var url = baseUrl + document.image;
  $http.get(url).success(function() {
    return true;
  })
  .error(function() {
    return false;
  });
};
```

which returns, if image path exists, that all works fine.
But I've tried this function with ng-if and it returns infinite loop error, I have no idea why. 
The idea is not to show document download button, if image path exists.

Comment: Suggestion: remove unnecessary HTML and fix syntax errors in JavaScript... (I guess you did some copy & paste and some lines were omitted)

Comment: How did you use the function with ng-if? It is not shown in your posted code. Btw, your `$scope.check` function returns nothing.

Comment: I changed code to one I tried with ng-if and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it cannot run a $http webservice in ng-if,
because ng-if execute the function in loop so fast without waiting for the $http response, and that what cause the errors.
The solution is to call the webService just once in ng-init, store the response value in a document related variable (the current item of filtered), and then check this variable in ng-if.

Controller

```
.controller('DocumentCtrl', function($http, $scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $cordovaFileTransfer, $cordovaFile, $window, localStorageService) {
  $scope.checkDownload = function(document) {
    var url = baseUrl + document.path;
    var filename = url.split("/").pop();
    $cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.documentsDirectory, filename)
    .then(function(success) {
      $scope.file[document.id] = true;
    }, function(error) {
      $scope.file[document.id] = false;
    });
  };
});
```

View

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="document in filtered = (documents | filter: searchFilter | filter: {category_id: categoryFilter.id}: false | orderBy: sortBy)"  type="item-text-wrap" ng-init="checkDownload(document)">
  <form class="view-form" name="viewForm" method="post" ng-submit="openLink(document, user)" ng-if="file[document.id] == false">
    <button type="submit"><img class="document-image" image-lazy-src="{{::url + document.thumbnail }}" alt="" image-lazy-loader="ios"/></button>
  </form>
  <form class="view-form" name="viewForm" method="post" ng-submit="openPath(document, user)" ng-if="file[document.id] == true">
    <button type="submit"><img class="document-image" image-lazy-src="{{::url + document.thumbnail }}" alt="" image-lazy-loader="ios"/></button>
  </form>
  <div class="document-title" ng-if="document.title.length <= 25">{{::document.title}} <span class="document-size">({{::document.size | filesize:2}})</span></div>
  <div class="document-title" ng-if="document.title.length > 25">{{::document.title | limitTo: 25}} ...<span class="document-size"> ({{::document.size | filesize:2}})</span></div>
  <div class="document-functions">
    <form name="downloadForm" method="post" ng-submit="download(document)">
      <button class="buttons button-document-save" ng-if="file[document.id] == false">Save</button>
    </form>
    <form name="sendForm" method="post" ng-submit="send(document, user, data)">
      <button class="buttons button-document-send">Email file</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```